# How do you find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of this projection matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$ with $m \geq n$ and linearly independent columns: $\begin{align*}
    A = \begin{bmatrix}\textbf{a}_1...\textbf{a}_n \end{bmatrix}\end{align*}.$

Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the projection matrix: $\begin{align*} P = I - A(A^*A)^{-1}A^*\end{align*}$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Try computing the matrix product $PA$ and $P^2$.